# jq get x levels of keys and remove all the rest

Tags: json, key, jq, depth

How can I get the first x levels of depth of an object and remove the rest using jq ?

I have the following example:

```json
{
  "Service1": {
    "Production": {
      "Location 1": {
        "b2d1": {
          "clusters": {
            "Datacenter2": []
          },
          "prod": {
            "clusters": {
              "Datacenter1": []
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "Service2": {
        "Production": {
          "Location 1": {
            "dr1": {
              "clusters": {
                "Datacenter3": []
              },
              "prod": {
                "clusters": {
                  "Datacenter1": []
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In my case, I want to get the 1st 3 levels (want to remove everything bellow location in all entries.

Answer (score 3):

From the question and example, it's not too clear how arrays should be handled, so the following may be of interest as it makes a clear distinction between JSON objects and all else:

```
# If the input is an object then:
#   if depth <= 0 then emit {}, otherwise map_values(retain(depth - 1));
#   otherwise echo the input.
def retain(depth):
  if type == "object"
  then if depth <= 0 then {}
       else map_values(retain(depth - 1))
       end
  else .
  end;

retain(3)
```

For the sample input, the output would be:

```
{
  "Service1": {
    "Production": {
      "Location 1": {},
      "Service2": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could get all the `paths` of `length > 3` (actually `== 4` would suffice), and delete those using `delpaths`:

```bash
jq 'delpaths([paths | select(length > 3)])' file.json
```

```json
{
  "Service1": {
    "Production": {
      "Location 1": {},
      "Service2": {}
    }
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/716K2olHRWB)

Note that `Service2` is already on third level, so it is cut off immediately (without going down to its own `Location 1` field).

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```
$ jq 'del(.[][][][])' file
{
  "Service1": {
    "Production": {
      "Location 1": {},
      "Service2": {}
    }
  }
}
$
```